# Convert Python instance-based program to Django database

Tags: python, django, kivy

My Python knowledge is primarily in back-end, non-GUI/non-web programming.
I have a program that simulates a fuel storage and transfer system. The primary program uses instances of valves, pumps, etc. to track system parameters (a database would probably make more sense, but classes for physics modeling made more sense at the time).

Below is an example of the Valve class:

```
class Valve:
def __init__(self, name="", sys_flow_in=0.0, sys_flow_out=0.0, drop=0.0, position=0, flow_coeff=0.0, press_in=0.0):
    self.name = name
    self.__position = int(position)  # Truncate float values for ease of calculations
    self.Cv = float(flow_coeff)
    self.flow_in = float(sys_flow_in)
    self.deltaP = float(drop)
    self.flow_out = float(sys_flow_out)
    self.press_out = 0.0
    self.press_in = press_in

def calc_coeff(self, diameter):
    self.Cv = 15 * math.pow(diameter, 2)

def press_drop(self, flow_out, spec_grav=1.0):
    try:
        x = (flow_out / self.Cv)
        self.deltaP = math.pow(x, 2) * spec_grav
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return "The valve coefficient must be > 0."

def valve_flow_out(self, flow_coeff, press_drop, spec_grav=1.0):
    try:
        if flow_coeff <= 0 or press_drop <= 0:
            raise ValueError("Input values must be > 0.")
        else:
            x = spec_grav / press_drop
            self.flow_out = flow_coeff / math.sqrt(x)
            return self.flow_out
    except ValueError:
        raise  # Re-raise error for testing

def get_press_out(self, press_in):
    if press_in:
        self.press_in = press_in  # In case the valve initialization didn't include it, or the value has changed
    self.press_drop(self.flow_out)
    self.press_out = self.press_in - self.deltaP

@property
def position(self):
    return self.__position

@position.setter
def position(self, new_position):
    try:
        if type(new_position) != int:
            raise TypeError("Integer values only.")
        else:
            self.__position = new_position
    except TypeError:
        raise  # Re-raise for testing

def open(self):
    self.__position = 100
    self.flow_out = self.flow_in
    self.press_out = self.press_in

def close(self):
    self.__position = 0
    self.flow_out = 0
    self.press_out = 0
    self.deltaP = 0
```

An instance would look like this:

```
gate1 = valve.Gate("Gate valve 1", sys_flow_in=tank1.flow_out, press_in=tank1.static_tank_press)
gate1.calc_coeff(16)
```

I have converted this to work with Kivy to provide a simplified human-machine interface (just adding buttons to the schematic file), as shown below: [image]

I want to write a Django version to showcase how the same back-end model can be used multiple ways. The problem is, since I have only completed a couple of Django tutorials, I'm not sure if Django is the best tool. Most tutorials concentrate on blogs, news articles, and the like, rather than a Kivy-like interface. Even looking at a variety of Django-powered sites showed similar concepts, rather than anything resembling an graphical HMI.

I was able to put the schematic into my Django code as a static file and add HTML buttons to it, so I think I just need to figure out how to bind the buttons to a database.

My questions are: is Django the best way to do this? I went w/ Django because it is the "gold standard" for Python web development, but suspect it may be the wrong tool for this.

Secondly, is there an easy way, or at least a methodology, for converting the classes/instances to database items? I suspect I will have to rewrite the code from scratch to make it work with a database, but if I don't have to do a lot of additional work, that would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 2**

Starting with your second question, converting your classes and instances to database items is quite simple in Django. Django has [Models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/), which is just a class but that maps 
(in general) to database table, and instances of that class map to a row in the table. The general process for existing Python classes to Django models is to have the class inherit from `django.db.models.Model` and change all instance variables to [model fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FloatField), which correspond to columns in the model's table in your database.

Below is a simple example for converting a plain Python class to a Django model:

```
class Valve:
    def __init__(self, name="", flow_coeff=0.0):
        self.name = name
        self.Cv = float(flow_coeff)

    def calc_coeff(self, diameter):
        self.Cv = 15 * math.pow(diameter, 2)
```

Becomes:

```
from django.db import models

class Valve(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    Cv = models.FloatField()

    def calc_coeff(self, diameter):
        self.Cv = 15 * math.pow(diameter, 2)
        self.save()
```

So Django models can still have methods and the constructor for both versions of the `Valve` class are the same, except that `save` or `create` must be used in order for the Django model version to be saved to the database.

Django also supports many different database management systems, with SQLite as the default (I generally use PostgreSQL). See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases for more on that.

**Question 1**

On whether or not Django is the right tool for the job: While this is a primarily opinion-based question, I believe Django is suitable for this problem. While most of the tutorials focus on Blogs and similar type sites, I think that is just because those examples are broadly applicable and easy to understand (and partially due to a lack of creativity). But Django can really be used to do anything. I've used it to create many different projects in different fields. In general, I use it for the Database management and as an API, and rarely use the front-end templates it offers.